# how to declare array within the object that will not be registered to 0 index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Good day!

I have an an object that needed to filled with some arrays of objects with a user click on a button so I declared my object like this:

```
var obj = {};
```

then I want the obj to have a column property so i add

```
obj['column'] = [];
```

but when I tried to "console.log(obj)" i get this result on fire bug!![image]

the 0th index shouldnt have that value, 0th index should have the value of the 1st index. I add some content on the object by

```
$('td', this).each(function(){
   obj['column'].push({value:"string here"}); 
 });
```

Is my declaration wrong or the way i push values? please help me figure this one out. Thank you and have a Good day!

Comment: I don't think you've supplied enough information to solve your problem. It seems likely that your `each` loop isn't running for index 0 (because there aren't any `td` elements being selected for some reason), but you haven't shown the surrounding code (both HTML and JS) that sets up the `each` execution. Could you provide a simple, complete example that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Thank you for figuring that one out for me @apsillers ! yeah youre correct, the loop wasn't running for index 0 because there were no td there.. only <th>, sorry for being so dumb that i needed others to figure  that one out for me. my code was running as it inteded to be, its just that I havent seen that one earlier. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
    var obj = {
        column: //Make column a property of object i.e. obj
            []

        };

$('td', this).each(function(){
    //push the value in obj property called column
    obj.column.push({value:"string here"});
 });
```